# Cant select ids that I loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that you need to use ".on" to use code that you loaded with jquery after the page has loaded. (At least I think it works that way)

So I tried that but it somehow just doesn't do a thing at all. No errors in the console either.

```
$("#forgot_password").click(function(){
  var forgot_password = '<div id="toLogin" style="cursor:pointer;">Prijava</div>'
  $("#loginPopupForm").html(forgot_password);                                       
});

$("#toLogin").on("click", function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

So when I click on #forgot_password it does execute the first click function. But when I click on #toLogin it doesn't do anything and I think its because its loaded with jquery when I click on #forgot_password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#loginPopupForm").on("click", "#toLogin", function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works! Sorry for the mistake I looked it up and everywhere I've seen it was done the way I did.

Comment: it would be cool to add why this is working and code in question did not work thankyou :)

Comment: Although 'on' is the replacement for 'live', it's sytax is different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to an element that **is** present when the page loads, like `body` for example. Just change your code to what is shown below

```
$("body").on("click", "#forgot_password", function(){
  var forgot_password = '<div id="toLogin" style="cursor:pointer;">Prijava</div>'
  $("#loginPopupForm").html(forgot_password);                                       
});

$("body").on("click", "#toLogin", function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `on` to the wrong thing.  You want it to be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#toLogin', function() {alert('hello') });
```

The id isn't there until you do the other click event, so jQuery is not finding any element to set the click event on.  You need to have an element that has been rendered in the DOM to set the event on.

Answer (score 0):

You are totally right about the problem : on() targets only elements that are already existing as it runs.
What you need in jQuery is called Delegated event and is well explained on the [Jquery doc page](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
The difference in the code is thin, but it's how you're supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the parent element

```
$("#toLogin").on("click","#loginPopupForm", function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

in the 2nd argument of the on

Comment: You have the wrong element selected.  `#toLogin` doesn't exist in the DOM.